# vlookup not working when unique identifier has spaces and/or slashes

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to do a VLOOKUP in excel, and I have, lets say the following unique identifiers:

```
Failure
Accept/Fail Okay
Accept/Fail N/A
Success
```

using the VLOOKUP, when i use Failure or Success as the unique identifier, it finds the data I am looking for, but if I try to VLOOKUP the other which spaces or slashes, it just returns #N/A.

Is there something I am missing?  like i said, the simple 1 word ones are found with no issues, but the others don't work.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Have you added the "FALSE" argument at the end to ensure that it is looking for an "exact match"?

Answer (score 2):

Tried this on my end and was able to reproduce the problem.

The solution appears to be to set the optional [range_lookup] argument to FALSE.  After doing this, I was able to perform successful lookups using all of the provided values.